# Load SharePoint Online list (with lookup columns) data from Excel via PowerQuery

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerquery

I am new to power query but not to SharePoint.
What i want to do is show in excel what i have in SharePoint.
I have created a very trivial example.

This is my SharePoint list:
[SharePoint List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4ZNO.png)

I have 2 columns. Title (default column) and LU1 (a lookup column to an external list, multi value enabled)

Now, in Excel Data > Get Data > From Online Services > From SharePoint Online List
I tried in two possible ways:

1. 1.0
2. 2.0 (Beta)

**1. 1.0**
after connecting, choosing the LU1 list and selecting the two columns, I click on the icon at the top right of the OData_MD1 column.
After a few seconds of "loading column names" ... "**no columns were found**"
[no columns were found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd3Ue.png)

**2.0 (Beta)**
after connecting, choosing the LU1 list and selecting the two columns, I click on the icon at the top right of the MD1 colums.
Now i can "Expand to New Rows" or "Extract Values...".

If I **Expand to New Rows**
[I Expand to New Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peLnw.png)
the column values go from "List" to "Record"
so I click again on the top ricght icon and I can select the field to show
[Select lookupValue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PsXJ.png)
but the rows with multiple values in the MD1 column are repeated, and this is not the result I want
[splitted rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S57Ff.png)

So I **Extract Values**
I choose to separate the values with commas
[comma separated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbtYS.png)
.... but I receive "Error" :(

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ey4cY.png)

what am I doing wrong?
many thanks in advance

Comment: When you click one of the error cells, what’s the error description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
I changed the function from:

= Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Other Columns", {"MD1", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text})

to:

= Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Other Columns", {"MD1", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(*, each Text.From(*[lookupValue])), ","), type text})

Of course it is strange that they put the functionality ready and selectable but then it goes wrong...

Comment: I had to change "lookupValue" by the name of the field ("MD1" in this example). Otherwise it worked great! Thanks